# Como criar um sumário com paginas numeradas do HTML para o DOCX

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, next.js

Estou gerando um relatório dinâmico em HTML usando o Editor.js em um projeto Next.js com a intenção de gerar o Docx ou PDF. Preciso incluir um sumário com link e pagina de todos os tópicos, tabelas e imagens contidos neste relatório. Qual seria a melhor forma de gerar esse relatório dinâmico com sumário automaticamente?

Answer (score -3):

Se quiser fazer isso no front-end, pode usar a biblioteca **jsPDF**. O comando para inserir links é este:

```js
doc.textWithLink('Page 2', x, y, { pageNumber: 2 });
```

E para docx existe a biblioteca **html-to-docx** no npm.

Ou pode usar **pdfmake** e **docx** se você tiver domínio sobre a estrutura do texto.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A complexidade está em determinar a página dos elementos já criados no html. E quanto a link deve ser um apontamento para cada item contido no relatório. Uma forma possivel seria utilizar o Paged.js talvez

Comment: Ajustei para refletir melhor a intenção de ir a uma página do próprio PDF